# Android BLE Scan in Background Service

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-broadcast, android-handler

I'm trying to make an Android app that will scan for a certain Bluetooth device as a background service.  Once the phone is within a certain range of the Bluetooth device, measured by reading the RSSI, the background service will start an Activity displayed to the user.  If the phone is moved out of range of the Bluetooth device, (after the RSSI value is beyond a certain threshold,) the Activity should be killed.

Here is the code for the background service:

```
public class BeaconScanService extends Service implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {

    private Service self = this;

    public static final String UNLOCK = "unlock";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String SIGNAL = "signal";
    public static final String GET_SIGNAL = "get_signal";

    //desired device to find
    private static final String targetMAC = "E1:BE:A8:1A:8B:A0";

    //class to handle saving RSSI values and detecting Bluetooth proximity
    private proxDetector proxy;

    //boolean to determine if phone is in BT range
    static boolean inProx = false;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Proximity Detector
        proxy = new proxDetector();

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        /*
         * We need to enforce that Bluetooth is first enabled, and take the
         * user to settings to enable it if they have not done so.
         */

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //Bluetooth is disabled
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            enableBtIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
        }

        /*
         * Check for Bluetooth LE Support.  In production, our manifest entry will keep this
         * from installing on these devices, but this will allow test devices or other
         * sideloads to report whether or not the feature exists.
         */
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No LE Support.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        //Begin scanning for LE devices
        startScan();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Cancel any scans in progress
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStopRunnable);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStartRunnable);
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    private Runnable mStopRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopScan();
        }
    };
    private Runnable mStartRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startScan();
        }
    };

    private void startScan() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Scan for Bluetooth device with specified MAC
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStopRunnable, 5000);
    }

    private void stopScan() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStartRunnable, 2500);
    }

    /* BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback */

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        /*
        * Create a new beacon and pass it up to the main thread
        */
        Toast.makeText(self, "OnLeScan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BT_Beacon beacon = new BT_Beacon(device.getAddress(), rssi);
        mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, 0, beacon));
    }

    /*
     * We have a Handler to process scan results on the main thread
     */
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(self, "Handlering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BT_Beacon beacon = (BT_Beacon) msg.obj;
            if(beacon.getAddress().equals(targetMAC)){//Only look for target device
                Toast.makeText(self, String.format("%ddBm", beacon.getSignal()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //HANDLE PROXIMITY DETECTION
                Intent i1 = new Intent(UNLOCK);
                proxy.processProx(beacon.getSignal());
                Intent i2 = new Intent(SIGNAL);
                i2.putExtra(GET_SIGNAL, proxy.prox);
                sendBroadcast(i2);
                if(proxy.crossedLine()){
                    i1.putExtra(STATUS, 1);
                    sendBroadcast(i1);
                    inProx = true;
                    Intent i = new Intent(self,MyActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    i1.putExtra(STATUS, 0);
                    sendBroadcast(i1);
                    inProx = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Ultimately I want this background service to be started on boot, but for testing purposes, I am able to create or destroy this service from an Activity that should also display the RSSI value:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        Button btnUnscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUnscan);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnUnscan.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BeaconScanService.SIGNAL));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnScan:
                Intent i = new Intent(this,BeaconScanService.class);
                startService(i);
                break;

            case R.id.btnUnscan:
                Intent i = new Intent(this,BeaconScanService.class);
                stopService(i);
                break;
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null) {
                int sig = bundle.getInt(BeaconScanService.GET_SIGNAL);
                TextView rssiView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_rssi);
                rssiView.setText(String.format("%ddBm", sig));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This is the layout for for MainActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUnscan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop Scan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnScan"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rssi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:text="dBm"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnUnscan"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in the activity that is started and ended by the BeaconScanService, the BroadcastReceiver is registered like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(beaconScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(BeaconScanService.UNLOCK));
}
```

and the BroadcastReceiver looks like this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver beaconScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            int status = bundle.getInt(BeaconScanService.STATUS);
            if(status == 0) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When I run this code, I can start and stop the BeaconScanService fine, and I know the service is scanning for the Bluetooth device due to debug Toasts being displayed.  As far as I can tell, the code breaks down somewhere in the Handler of the service.  No RSSI value is displayed in the TextView, and MyActivity is not started when the phone is brought close enough to the Bluetooth device.

I'm not too familiar with the interprocess communication aspects of Android programming, so I'm probably doing something wrong there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify your question, what exactly do you want?